# key error while grouping for a present key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, keyerror

I am trying to execute this - 
but it gives a key error for site_id while site_id is present in my dataset.
I have double checked the spellings but this problem still persists.Traceback is exceptionally long to paste here.

```
air_temperature_filler = 
pd.DataFrame(weather_df.groupby(['site_id','day','month']) 
['air_temperature'].mean(),columns=["air_temperature"])
weather_df.update(air_temperature_filler,overwrite=False)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how the table `weather_df` is structured? Could you also fix the indentation in your code? it is not clear when a line ends and a new one starts

Comment: Never mind I fixed it ... The index needed to be reset before grouping. Thanks for taking the time.